# Polymorphic Smart Pointer Array as Argument

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, polymorphism

I want a static 2D array that takes an interface class pointer.

Using raw pointer `Base* rawr[5][5]` works fine but I want to work with smart pointers and only pass the raw pointer as an argument.

How can I make the code work without changing the args to smart pointers?

```cpp
class Base {};

class Child : public Base {};

void Foo(Base* array[5][5])
{
    // Stuff
}
void OtherFoo(std::unique_ptr<Base> array[5][5])
{
    // Stuff
}

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Base> rawr[5][5];
    
    // argument of type "std::unique_ptr<Base, std::default_delete<Base>> (*)[5]" 
    // is incompatible with parameter of type "Base *(*)[5]"
    Foo(rawr);

    // no suitable conversion function from 
    // "std::unique_ptr<Base, std::default_delete<Base>>" to "Base *(*)[5]" exists
    Foo(rawr[5][5]);
    
    // expression must have class type but it has type 
    // "std::unique_ptr<Base, std::default_delete<Base>> (*)[5]"
    Foo(rawr.get());

    // expression must have pointer-to-class type but it has type 
    // "std::unique_ptr<Base, std::default_delete<Base>> (*)[5]"
    Foo(rawr->get());


    // This works 
    OtherFoo(rawr);
}
```

Newbie question + probably a duplicate but after googling for a while I didn't see an answer, sorry :'(

Comment: why do you think you need to do this?

Comment: _"I want to work with smart pointers and only pass the raw pointer as an argument"_ - Why? You could just add a typedef: `using fivexfive_base_array = std::array<std::array<std::unique_ptr<Base>, 5>, 5>;` and use that everywhere. Take it by reference in the functions. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/49r8fK6hz). Also: Don't forget to add a `virtual ~Base() = default;` destructor to `Base` since you'll be destroying objects via base class destructors.

Comment: Why are you using C-style arrays rather than [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)?

Comment: Thanks I'll try it that way, though I'm still not sure why my way is flawed yet.. I think I might be misunderstanding how smart pointers work lol @TedLyngmo

Comment: @segragationofthenation It's flawed because you try to pass something on to a function but there's no possible conversion that could make it legal. What do you mean by _"Using an array with polymorphic types"_? Yes, I see that. That's why I suggested that you add a `virtual` base class destructor.

Comment: Well It's because I have a board with cells and every cell can hold a different object derived from the Base class so in my head its "oh just have an array of pointers to the base class but make them smart pointers so you dont have to worry about deleting them later"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I make the code work without changing the args to smart pointers?

You can't pass around an array of smart pointers where an array of raw pointers is expected.  However, you can have 2 separate arrays - an array of smart pointers, and an array of raw pointers that point to the objects that the smart pointers are managing, eg:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() = default; 
};

class Child : public Base {};

void Foo(Base* array[5][5])
{
    // Stuff
}

void OtherFoo(std::unique_ptr<Base> array[5][5])
{
    // Stuff
}

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Base> smartr[5][5];
    Base* rawr[5][5];
    
    // fill smartr as needed...

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; ++j) {
            rawr[i][j] = smartr[i][j].get();
        }
    }

    Foo(rawr);
    OtherFoo(smartr);
}
```